# How can I use arrays of references in SQLite?

Tags: arrays, sqlite

I am implementing a system to represent a school schedule in SQL, and I want to have a table called `Student` which includes all of the student's classes. do i need to include references to a `Class` table as attributes `class1,class2,class3,...,class12`
 or can I use a sort of array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using relational database, it would be good to make a m:n relationship between Student and Class table. It would mean that you will have Student table with primary key student_id, Class table with primary key class_id, and one more table, called StudentClass with foreign keys fk_student_id and fk_class_id, plus some additional properties (depending on what do you want to achieve). That would be a good relational design.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a field filled with a comma separated list, or you could keep a separate table of 'allowed classes', with associated data (unique ID number, name, description, teacher), then use foreign keys and an intermediate table to implement a many to many relationship of students to classes.

- [Many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)
- [Foreign keys in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Support for foreign keys in SQLite is pretty good these days, and all the features you'll likely want are there.